# system responsiveness under compilation

Tags: arch-linux

**Long story short**, I'd like to know how to *fix* system responsiveness under heavy compilation session.

---

**Full story**, I am on Arch Linux and I used to compile *-ck* kernel **[1]** for my CPU architecture, that is `MAKEFLAGS="-j4"` for using all CPU's cores and `-march=native`.
During this task I can perfectly use **already opened application**, heavy tasks too e.g. watching a video with my browser, if it was already opened before launching compilation.
Problems come when I want to **launch any other new application** because they stuck or never load
*e.g. launching nautilus file-manager comes in a blank window (with working UI but no content) or another instance of firefox makes the new window appear only when compilation ends/CPU load lowers down*
How can I set a lower CPU priority for compilation?

---

**[1]** https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/linux-ck/